# authentication with only username (id) in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, passwords, backend

I'm creating a Laravel project where I would like to add authentication based on only username or ID. the point is that you can connect your client to a device with a certain ID.

Goal: I go to the page, type the ID of the product I'm holding and the device gets logged in on the products account.

I've tried taking out all password fields on make:auth files and I can now register without a password but when I try to login to the account I created it just stays at the page. it doesn't need to be super secure.

Does anyone know what file/function I need to change so it will work?

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge($request->only($this->email()));
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/huidtype';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    }
```

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\User;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

    class RegisterController extends Controller
    {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
        ]);
    }




    }
```

login.blade.php

```php
        @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Login') }}
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Register.blade.php

```php
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                            @csrf

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                    @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                    @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback">
                                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Register') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

After trying a solution provided by @Option i am getting the following error:

```
Class Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User contains 3 abstract method and
must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
(Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthPassword)
```

Here is the file the error is occurring in:

```php
    namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

    class User extends Model implements
        AuthenticatableContract,
        AuthorizableContract,
        CanResetPasswordContract
    {
        use Authenticatable, Authorizable;
    }
```

Comment: Why on earth would you make it username based only?

Comment: We need to see what you have tried along with the code.. We can't just guess what's already been changed etc

Comment: Did you see `Auth::loginUsingId(id)` ?

Comment: @Option I can't just upload the code of 15+ php files...

Comment: We don't want 15 files we want lines of code where the issue is occurring... I have flagged this to be closed due to lack of information provided and no code. Please review your question and edit accordingly.

Comment: @Option If you have even read the question you would know the problem is that nothing happens. thus i don know where the problem is. if you don know the answer why bother...

Comment: It's quite clear you don't come here often...

Comment: As Above... *We need to see what you have tried*

Comment: @Option i said "i've tried taking out all password fields on make:auth files". read the damn question

Comment: @Option you asked for it.

Comment: Thank you. I will read through now and come back with an answer. :)

Comment: Have you removed password sections from `AuthenticatesUsers.php` file? as password is within the validation. This is why it's failing. You have removed the field so it won't return the error

Comment: You can create a user like you post a comment. That isn't a very difficult job. Now you set a session variable a true/false for if you don't need a super secure login process. In your controller, redirect form action to a custom function and if credentials are good then : `Session::set('isLoggedIn', true);`. Top simplest idea for supercomputers!

Comment: @Option i put an error on the original question that occured after i tried your solution.

Comment: Go into Authenticable and remove `public function getAuthPassword() `

Comment: @Option Already had that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your login controller. You need to override the auth:make credentials function to customize according to your need.

```php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            $this->username() => 'required|string',
        ]);
    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge($request->only($this->username()));
    }

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. however its not working right now. could you explain where you got "username()" from? is that the column name?

Comment: here username is the one and only field required for logging in user. you can also do it with email_id.

Comment: there is none. it just stays at the login page. my guess is that somewhere is still looks for a password and tries to indicate that by saying "you need to fill in password". but since i removed the password field it won show?

Comment: did you tried `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan view:clear` ??   change this `protected $redirectTo = '/huidtype';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` in login controller.

Comment: @Niels I have updated the controller code with a new function which also needs to be override so try with this updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass the hidden input field to change password input text field

```
<input type='hidden' name='password' value='0'>
```

then edit migration of user table to make password automaticly input 0 with bcrypt()

```
$table->string('password')->default(bcrypt(0));
```